# Linux как прокси для андроида

Tags: linux, https, proxy

Как в Линуксе настроить https прокси сервер, чтобы https трафик смартфона мог идти через него?

Comment: Если вам нужно еще и просматривать траффик - смотрите в сторону mitmproxy. Настраивать надо будет даже не проксю, а перенаправление портов в таком случае.

Comment: коротко: никак. проксирование подразумевает изменение проходящих пакетов, а протокол https как раз и гарантирует, что пакет либо придёт точно таким же, каким его отправили, либо не придёт вовсе. это противоречие разрешимо только при эксплуатации каких-нибудь уязвимостей систем (в т.ч., например, кража ключа шифрования).

Comment: Ну почему же сразу "никак "? Есть варианты с созданием соответствующих  сертификатов и внедрении их на телефон.